# How to copy and paste in XML part2

Tags: xslt

I have a XML file where I want to copy a text node value (eg: CIAV819) from element with attribute=ruleId and paste it to next node element with attribute=ruleExpression. Below is the XML file that I want to modify:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <Main>
            <installObj uniqueObjects="2822">
                <object class="Installer">
                    <visualChildren>
                        <object class="InstallSet">
                            <installchildrenMain>
                                <object class="com.zerog.ia.installer.InstallBundle1">
                                    <property name="ruleExpression">
                                        <string><![CDATA[]]></string>  ---paste1
                                    </property>
                                    <property name="bundleName">
                                        <string><![CDATA[Australia]]></string>
                                    </property>
                                    <rules logicalOperation="AND">
                                        <object class="CompareVariable">
                                            <property name="ruleId">
                                               <string><![CDATA[CIAV819]]></string> --copy1
                                            </property>
                                            <property name="operandOne">
                                               <string><![CDATA[$FEATURE$]]></string>
                                            </property>
                                        </object>
                                    </rules>
                                    <installChildren>
                                        <object class="com.zerog.ia.installer.InstallComponent1">
                                            <property name="ruleExpression">
                                                <string><![CDATA[]]></string>  --paste2
                                            </property>    
                                            <property name="componentName">
                                                <string><![CDATA[AUST]]></string>
                                            </property>
                                            <rules logicalOperation="AND">
                                                <object class="CompareVariable">
                                                    <property name="ruleId">
                                                        <string><![CDATA[CIAV962]]></string> --copy2.1
                                                    </property>
                                                    <property name="operandOne">
                                                 <string><![CDATA[$FEATURE$]]></string>
                                           </property>
                                                 </object>
                                                 <object class="CompareVariable">
                                 <property name="ruleId">
                                    <string><![CDATA[CIAV503]]></string> --copy2.2
                  </property>
                                                 </object>
                                                </rules>
                                            <installChildren>
                                                <object class="com.zerog.ia.installer.InstallDirCont">
                                                    <property name="ruleExpression">
                                                        <string><![CDATA[]]></string>  --paste3
                                                    </property>
                                                    <property name="operandOne">
                                                 <string><![CDATA[$FEATURE$]]></string>
                                         </property>
                                                    <rules logicalOperation="OR">
                                                        <object class="CompareVariable1">
                                                            <property name="ruleId">
                                                                <string><![CDATA[CIAV100]]></string> --COPY3.1 </property>
                                                            <property name="operandOne">
                                                        <string><![CDATA[$FEATURE$]]></string>  </property>

                                                        </object>
                                                        <object class="CompareVariable2">
                                                            <property name="ruleId">
                                                                <string><![CDATA[CIAV200]]></string><!-- COPY3.2 -->
                                                            </property>
                                                            <property name="operandOne">
                                                       <string><![CDATA[$FEATURE$]]></string>
                                                </property>

                                                        </object>
                                                    </rules>
                                                </object>
                                            </installChildren>
                                        </object><!-- end of installComponent1 -->
                                        <object class="com.zerog.ia.installer.InstallComponent2" >
                                            <!--
                                            Same as above (Install Component1)
                                            -->
                                        </object><!-- end of installComponent2 -->
                                    </installChildren>   
                                </object><!-- end of installBundle1 -->

                                <object class="com.zerog.ia.installer.InstallBundle2" >
                                    <property name="ruleExpression">
                                        <string><![CDATA[]]></string>  ---paste4
                                    </property>
                                    <property name="bundleName">
                                        <string><![CDATA[** ** Database]]></string>
                                    </property>
                                    <rules logicalOperation="AND">
                                        <object class="CompareVariable">
                                            <property name="ruleId">
                                               <string><![CDATA[CIAV111]]></string> --copy4
                                            </property>
                                            <property name="operandOne">
                                               <string><![CDATA[something]]></string>
                                            </property>
                                        </object>
                                    </rules>
                                    <installChildren>
                                        <object class="com.zerog.ia.installer.InstallComponent1">
                                            <property name="ruleExpression">
                                                <string><![CDATA[]]></string>  --paste5
                                            </property>    
                                            <property name="componentName">
                        <string><![CDATA[Common]]></string>
                            </property>
                                            <rules logicalOperation="AND">
                                                <object class="CompareVariable">
                                                    <property name="ruleId">
                                                        <string><![CDATA[]]></string> --copy5.1 
</property>
                                                    <property name="operandOne">
                                                 <string><![CDATA[$FEATURE$]]></string>
                                           </property>
                                                 </object>
                                                 <object class="CompareVariable">
                                               <property name="ruleId">
                                    <string><![CDATA[]]></string> --copy5.2
                  </property>
                                                 </object>
                                                </rules>
                                </object><!-- end of installBundle2 -->
                            </installchildrenMain>
                        </object><!-- end of InstallSet -->
                    </visualChildren><!-- end of visualChildren -->
                </object><!-- end of Installer -->
            </installObj>
            <restorationObjects count="0"/>
        </Main>
```

Copy ‘CIAV819’ value from copy1 location to paste1 location and similarly for other copy2 and copy3 locations. Wherein for example paste1 location should look like this:

```
<property name="ruleExpression">
   <string><![CDATA[CIAV819]]></string>  ---paste1
</property>
```

paste2 location should look like:

```
<property name="ruleExpression">
   <string><![CDATA[CIAV962 && CIAV503]]></string>  ---paste2
</property>
```

paste3 location should look like:

```
<property name="ruleExpression">
   <string><![CDATA[CIAV100 || CIAV200]]></string>  ---paste3
</property>
```

but only paste5 text node should remain blank as copy5.1 and copy5.2 text nodes are empty. I.e. under `<object class="InstallBundle2" >` when its

```
<property name="bundleName">
   <string><![CDATA[** ** Database]]></string>
 </property>
```

One of its InstallComponent under this which has the

```
<property name="componentName">
    <string><![CDATA[Common]]></string>
</property>
```

should have paste5 as empty like this :

```
<property name="ruleExpression">
       <string><![CDATA[]]></string>  ---paste5
    </property>
```

I am using the below XSLT transformation to get my output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="string" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object[starts-with(@class, 'com.zerog.ia.installer.Install')]/property[@name='ruleExpression']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <string>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::rules[1]" mode="copy" />
         </string>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object[starts-with(@class, 'com.zerog.ia.installer.actions.InstallDirCont')]/property[@name='ruleExpression']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <string>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::rules[1]" mode="copy" />
         </string>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rules" mode="copy">
    <xsl:variable name="operator">
       <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@logicalOperation='OR'"> || </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise> &amp;&amp; </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="object/property[@name='ruleId']/string">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1"><xsl:value-of select="$operator" /></xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And I am running this XSLT in my PHP file (shown below) which is processing this xml/xslt files:

```
<?php
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('ELS92.iap_xml');

$xsldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xsldoc->load('transform.xslt');

$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$xslt->importStylesheet($xsldoc);

$result = $xslt->transformToDoc($xmldoc);
$result->save($xmldoc);
?>
```

Once I run this XSLT my paste5 looks like this:

```
<property name="ruleExpression">
 <string><![CDATA[ && ]]>
</string>
</property>
```

which is not right!

Also how can I debug my xslt? Can I output the xslt processing to some text file?Bcoz sometimes mycomplete xml goes blank may be bcoz it couldnt find some required template?

Thanks

Comment: Please stop making such radical edits to questions that have already been answered.  Your latest edit completely invalidated the accepted answer.  If you have a different question then you should ask it _as a different question_, not as an edit to an existing question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your "paste 5" you are doing a `for-each` over two nodes both of which have the empty string property value, so it's correctly doing empty string + `" && "` + empty string.  What you need to do is filter the list of nodes you're processing so that list only includes the non-empty ones:

```
<xsl:template match="rules" mode="copy">
    <xsl:variable name="operator">
       <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@logicalOperation='OR'"> || </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise> &amp;&amp; </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="object/property[@name='ruleId']/string[normalize-space()]">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1"><xsl:value-of select="$operator" /></xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The predicate on `string` means that in case 5 this will select *no* nodes rather than two (`normalize-space()` gives you the value of the node with leading and trailing whitespace stripped and all internal runs of consecutive whitespace characters collapsed to a single space - this will be the empty string if the value is empty or contains only whitespace, and an empty string means "false" when used as a predicate).